# Nested conditional types break typescript inferring

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Why does first type not work and the second one works?

```
type IsMessage<T> = T extends { message: unknown } ? true: false

// type 1

type MessageOfA<T> = IsMessage<T> extends true ? T["message"] : never;

//error output - Type '"message"' cannot be used to index type 'T'.



// type 2  

type MessageOfB<T> = T extends { message: unknown } ? T["message"] : never
```

Comment: Which version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: 4.7.2 Typescript  version

Comment: You can't rely on in-between result of types. Inside of `IsMessage` you have checked the type of `T`, but that will be forgotten by the time you get to `MessageOfA`. In general it's mostly useless to do `? true : false` in types.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is this really any different from:

```
declare const t: unknown;

function IsMessage(t: any) {
    return "message" in t;
}

if (IsMessage(t)) {
    t.message // 't' is not type { message: any }
}
```

aside the fact that it's with types and not "real code"?

You can see in [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQx21W) that it is not.